# How do I avoid implicit conversions on non-constructing functions?

Tags: c++, function, casting, implicit-conversion

How do I avoid implicit casting on non-constructing functions?
I have a function that takes an integer as a parameter,
but that function will also take characters, bools, and longs.
I believe it does this by implicitly casting them.
How can I avoid this so that the function only accepts parameters of a matching type, and will refuse to compile otherwise?
There is a keyword "explicit" but it does not work on non-constructing functions. :\
what do I do?

The following program compiles, although I'd like it not to:

```
#include <cstdlib>

//the function signature requires an int
void function(int i);

int main(){

    int i{5};
    function(i); //<- this is acceptable

    char c{'a'};
    function(c); //<- I would NOT like this to compile

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void function(int i){return;}
```

*please be sure to point out any misuse of terminology and assumptions

Comment: by the way, the ability to pass a char, long, bool, or basically any other integer type where an int is expected is because of integer promotion and conversion rules that are built into the language. This is a different mechanism than the implicit conversions done with non-explicit constructors.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

## 8 years later (PRE-C++20, see edit):

The most modern solution, if you don't mind template functions -which you may mind-, is to use a templated function with `std::enable_if` and `std::is_same`.

Namely:

```cpp
// Where we want to only take int
template <class T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<T,int>,bool> = true>
void func(T x) {
    
}
```

## EDIT (c++20)

I've recently switched to c++20 and I believe that there is a better way. **If your team or you don't use c++20, or are not familiar with the new concepts library, do not use this.** This is much nicer and the intended method as outlines in the new c++20 standard, and by the writers of the new feature (read a papers written by Bjarne Stroustrup [here](https://www.stroustrup.com/good_concepts.pdf).

```
template <class T>
    requires std::same_as(T,int)
void func(T x) {
    //...
}
```

### Small Edit (different pattern for concepts)

The following is a much better way, because it explains your reason, to have an explicit int. If you are doing this frequently, and would like a good pattern, I would do the following:

```
template <class T>
concept explicit_int = std::same_as<T,int>;

template <explicit_int T>
void func(T x) {

}
```

### Small edit 2 (the last I promise)

Also a way to accomplish this possibility:

```
template <class T>
concept explicit_int = std::same_as<T,int>;

void func(explicit_int auto x) {

}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I'm switching this to the accepted answer now.

Comment: @TrevorHickey Check out my edit, I've been learning more about modern c++ and c++20. Concepts are a great formalization of the benefits that SFINAE give.

Comment: Yes, concepts are good addition to your answer.  I've heard it's bad practice to use concepts for constraining a single type, but it's still a valid answer here.

Comment: @TrevorHickey I would agree; I wonder what the compiler tax is like when using it too frequently. I put another edit up there which is a much better way to use concepts in this scenario (and generally when restraining types). Interesting syntax.

Comment: I love the [abbreviated function template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template) syntax usage in your "Small edit 2" example. Being able to put a bunch of concepts in a common header file and then using them with that simple syntax is great!

Comment: I think the first code chunk should have `std::is_same_v<T,int>` for C++17 (or, `std::is_same<T,int>::value` for pre C++17) instead of `std::is_same<T,int>`.

Comment: @submartingale Right you are. I edited it now.

Answer (score 97):

Define function template which matches all other types:

```
void function(int); // this will be selected for int only

template <class T>
void function(T) = delete; // C++11
```

This is because non-template functions with direct matching are always considered first. Then the function template with direct match are considered - so never `function<int>` will be used. But for anything else, like char, `function<char>` will be used - and this gives your compilation errrors:

```
void function(int) {}

template <class T>
void function(T) = delete; // C++11 


int main() {
   function(1);
   function(char(1)); // line 12
}
```

ERRORS:

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:4:6: error: deleted function 'void function(T) [with T = char]'
prog.cpp:12:20: error: used here
```

**pre-C++11 way:**

```
// because this ugly code will give you compilation error for all other types
class DeleteOverload
{
private:
    DeleteOverload(void*);
};


template <class T>
void function(T a, DeleteOverload = 0);

void function(int a)
{}
```

**[UPDATE 9/24/2023] C++23 version**

Since C++23 we might use `static_assert(false, msg)` to have more clear message to user, due to C++23 fixing DR that allow static_assert of non-value-dependent expressions in a template context:

```
void function(int) {} // this will be selected for int only

template <class T>
void function(T) {
    // since C++23
    static_assert(false, "function shall be called for int only");
} 
int main() {
    function(1);
    // function(1l);
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^ produces error:
    // error: static assertion failed: function shall be called for int only
    // 5 |     static_assert(false, "function shall be called for int only");
}
```

**[END UPDATE 9/24/2023]**

Comment: for me the assertions fails even when function is called only with int parameters

Comment: @GeoffReedy - static_assert always happens - no matter if instatianted or not. I updated my answer - now it works

Comment: Works great for me. Combined with some macro's, I made my own versions of `hton` and `ntoh` functions that will only work with the right type.

Comment: Thank you!   I had a worse case, f(string&, string&) and f(bool, string&) where I was forwarding the bool call to the f(string&, string&) case, and I couldn't understand why everything was getting directed to the bool case.  After reading this I realized that *everything* is convertible to bool!   The template solution saved my bacon and sanity, and showed the conversion compile error that explained why my string case wasn't getting called.

Comment: This answer is perfect. It also seems to work great with constructors as well, preventing the need for "explicit" while still preventing implicit conversions. This means that you can use `return {...}` without worrying about implicit conversions occurring. This answer is also a lot better than the SFINAE based solutions as those mess around with name mangling while this solution leaves the function signatures alone that are actually allowed.

Answer (score 27):

You can't directly, because a `char` automatically gets promoted to `int`.

You can resort to a trick though: create a function that takes a `char` as parameter and don't implement it. It will compile, but you'll get a linker error:

```
void function(int i) 
{
}
void function(char i);
//or, in C++11
void function(char i) = delete;
```

Calling the function with a `char` parameter will break the build.

See http://ideone.com/2SRdM

Terminology: non-construcing functions? Do you mean a function that is not a constructor?

Comment: non-constructing functions? Do you mean a function that is not a constructor? I do

Comment: Since the OP uses C++11, we can `=delete` it and get a [compilation error](http://ideone.com/1tND3), not a linker error.

Comment: @ybungalobill c++11 solutions are good.  I thought I could only delete functions that are operators inside classes though

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yes, because of the initializer list syntax for i and c

Comment: @ybungalobill you should add that as the answer, it's much better.

Comment: @ybungalobill missed the link you posted . I see it now

Comment: The OP mentioned some other types in addition to `char`. Possibly the number of undesired actual argument types is unbounded. So the general case would call for a rather large number of function declarations. The "obvious" solution there is to templatize. But then, one removes the possibility of having a general templated overload.

Comment: There is no "automatic promotion" for function arguments, unless we are matching a C-style variadic function. In the first sentence you meant that there is an implicit conversion from `char` to `int`.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a general solution that causes an error at compile time if `function` is called with anything but an int

```
template <typename T>
struct is_int { static const bool value = false; };

template <>
struct is_int<int> { static const bool value = true; };


template <typename T>
void function(T i) {
  static_assert(is_int<T>::value, "argument is not int");
  return;
}

int main() {
  int i = 5;
  char c = 'a';

  function(i);
  //function(c);

  return 0;
}
```

It works by allowing any type for the argument to function but using `is_int` as a type-level predicate. The generic implementation of `is_int` has a false value but the explicit specialization for the int type has value true so that the static assert guarantees that the argument has exactly type `int` otherwise there is a compile error.

Comment: this is a good solution, but if I do this for a lot of functions, won't I have a lot of structs sitting around in my executable?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. No instances of the struct are ever created, it is only used to resolve the constant `value`.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use a struct to make the second function private:

```
#include <cstdlib>

struct NoCast {
    static void function(int i);
  private:
    static void function(char c);
};

int main(){

    int i(5);
    NoCast::function(i); //<- this is acceptable

    char c('a');
    NoCast::function(c); //<- Error

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void NoCast::function(int i){return;}
```

This won't compile:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:7: error: ‘static void NoCast::function(char)’ is private
prog.cpp:16: error: within this context
```

Comment: a fair answer, but I'd perfer to avoid scoping

Comment: I think this is the best answer if you just want to prevent one particular type of argument.  It works for any version of C++ , involves a *lot* less typing, and it is an immediate compile time error.  That said, the template answers (above) are able to hide all argument types you don't want, but they require C++11.

Answer (score 2):

For C++14 (and I believe C++11), you can disable copy constructors by overloading rvalue-references as well:

Example:
Say you have a base `Binding<C>` class, where `C` is either the base `Constraint` class, or an inherited class. Say you are storing `Binding<C>` by value in a vector, and you pass a reference to the binding and you wish to ensure that you do not cause an implicit copy.

You may do so by deleting `func(Binding<C>&& x)` (per PiotrNycz's example) for rvalue-reference specific cases.

Snippet:

```
template<typename T>
void overload_info(const T& x) {
  cout << "overload: " << "const " << name_trait<T>::name() << "&" << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void overload_info(T&& x) {
  cout << "overload: " << name_trait<T>::name() << "&&" << endl;
}

template<typename T>
void disable_implicit_copy(T&& x) = delete;

template<typename T>
void disable_implicit_copy(const T& x) {
  cout << "[valid] ";
  overload_info<T>(x);
}

...

int main() {
  Constraint c;
  LinearConstraint lc(1);

  Binding<Constraint> bc(&c, {});
  Binding<LinearConstraint> blc(&lc, {});

  CALL(overload_info<Binding<Constraint>>(bc));
  CALL(overload_info<Binding<LinearConstraint>>(blc));

  CALL(overload_info<Binding<Constraint>>(blc));

  CALL(disable_implicit_copy<Binding<Constraint>>(bc));
  // // Causes desired error
  // CALL(disable_implicit_copy<Binding<Constraint>>(blc));
}
```

Output:

```
>>> overload_info(bc)
overload: T&&

>>> overload_info<Binding<Constraint>>(bc)
overload: const Binding<Constraint>&

>>> overload_info<Binding<LinearConstraint>>(blc)
overload: const Binding<LinearConstraint>&

>>> overload_info<Binding<Constraint>>(blc)
implicit copy: Binding<LinearConstraint>  ->  Binding<Constraint>
overload: Binding<Constraint>&&

>>> disable_implicit_copy<Binding<Constraint>>(bc)
[valid] overload: const Binding<Constraint>&
```

Error (with `clang-3.9` in `bazel`, when offending line is uncommented):

```
cpp_quick/prevent_implicit_conversion.cc:116:8: error: call to deleted function 'disable_implicit_copy'
  CALL(disable_implicit_copy<Binding<Constraint>>(blc));
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Full Source Code: [prevent_implicit_conversion.cc](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/39978e0/cpp_quick/prevent_implicit_conversion.cc#L99)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was going to answer this with the code below, but even though it works with Visual C++, in the sense of producing the desired compilation error, MinGW g++ 4.7.1 accepts it, and invokes the rvalue reference constructor!

I think it must be a compiler bug, but I could be wrong, so – anyone?

Anyway, here's the code, which *may* turn out to be a standard-compliant solution (or, it may turn out that that's a thinko on my part!):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>      // std::is_same, std::enable_if
using namespace std;

template< class Type >
struct Boxed
{
    Type value;

    template< class Arg >
    Boxed(
        Arg const& v,
        typename enable_if< is_same< Type, Arg >::value, Arg >::type* = 0
        )
        : value( v )
    {
        wcout << "Generic!" << endl;
    }

    Boxed( Type&& v ): value( move( v ) )
    {
        wcout << "Rvalue!" << endl;
    }
};

void function( Boxed< int > v ) {}

int main()
{
    int i = 5;
    function( i );  //<- this is acceptable

    char c = 'a';
    function( c );  //<- I would NOT like this to compile
}
```

Comment: Oh man - look at my 2 line solution: `template <class T> void function(T) = delete;`....

Comment: @PiotrNycz: yes, I saw that - after I wrote the above code. I think it's nifty, nice, but also quite limited, since you cannot have a templated overload. The above would be a more general, reusable solution, if it should turn out to be standard compliant.

Comment: Simple forwarding + decay on the SFINAE check does the trick AFAICT: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ff6323ac11496981. I agree that there is no satisfactory solution (this one will not allow for reference arguments, unless using more wrappers)

Comment: This comes even close, I suppose: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06a6be3e8f31094e

Answer (score 1):

I first tried PiotrNycz's approach (for C++03, which I'm forced to use for a project), then I tried to find a more general approach and came up with this `ForcedType<T>` template class.

```c++
template <typename T>
struct ForcedType {
    ForcedType(T v): m_v(v) {}
    operator T&() { return m_v; }
    operator const T&() const { return m_v; }

private:
    template <typename T2>
    ForcedType(T2);

    T m_v;
};

template <typename T>
struct ForcedType<const T&> {
    ForcedType(const T& v): m_v(v) {}
    operator const T&() const { return m_v; }

private:
    template <typename T2>
    ForcedType(const T2&);

    const T& m_v;
};

template <typename T>
struct ForcedType<T&> {
    ForcedType(T& v): m_v(v) {}
    operator T&() { return m_v; }
    operator const T&() const { return m_v; }

private:
    template <typename T2>
    ForcedType(T2&);

    T& m_v;
};
```

If I'm not mistaken, those three specializations should cover all common use cases. I'm not sure if a specialization for rvalue-reference (on C++11 onwards) is actually needed or the by-value one suffices.

One would use it like this, in case of a function with 3 parameters whose 3rd parameter doesn't allow implicit conversions:

```c++
function(ParamType1 param1, ParamType2 param2, ForcedType<ParamType3> param3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a clean, simple solution in C++11 using enable_if. This example uses std::is_same for the predicate, but you can use any other constexpr yielding bool.

```
#include <type_traits> // type_traits has enable_if

// take will only accept double, whereas 'normal' functions
// taking double would also accept e.g. float arguments

// compile this with clang++ to get:
// $ clang++ limit*.cc
// limit_argtypes.cc:16:3: error: no matching function for call to 'take'
//   take ( 1.0f ) ;
//   ^~~~
// limit_argtypes.cc:10:6: note: candidate template ignored: requirement
// 'std::is_same<float, double>::value' was not satisfied
// [with arg_t = float]
// void take ( arg_t rhs )
//      ^
// 1 error generated.

// The error message is even clear and concise.

template < typename arg_t ,
           typename = typename std::enable_if
                      < std::is_same < arg_t , double > :: value
                      > :: type
          >
void take ( arg_t rhs )
{ }

int main ( int argc , char * argv[] )
{
  take ( 1.0 ) ;
  take ( 1.0f ) ;
}
```