# Prevent wrapping lambda in std::function with different types

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class that takes in its constructor a `std::function<void(T)>`. If I declare T to be a double, but pass the constructor a lambda that takes an int, the compiler let's me get away without a warning. (Update: MSVC issues a warning, clang does not). Is it possible to modify this code so that I get a compiler error (w/ clang)?

I was surprised this works:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Thing {
public:
  using Handler = std::function<void(T)>;

  Thing(Handler handler)
  : handler_(handler)
  {}

  Handler handler_;
};

int main() {

  Thing<double> foo([](int bar) {  // Conversion to void(int) from void(double)
    std::cout << bar;
  });

  foo.handler_(4.2);

  return 0;
}
```

...and compiles without a warning:

```
$ clang --std=c++11 -lc++ -Wall -Werror test.cc
$ ./a.out
4
```

It seems like such a conversion could result in unwanted side effects. I can't imagine a case where this would ever be desired behavior.

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think it works because a double can be implicitly cast to an int, not that the function object is being converted.

Comment: Relevant question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877546/how-do-i-avoid-implicit-casting-on-non-constructing-functions-c

Comment: It's not converting a std::function<void(int)> to a std::function<void(double)>.  It's wrapping a lambda in a std::function<void(double)>.  And you're actually explicitly requesting it.

Comment: This does post a warning in Visual Studios 2015 (C4244).

Comment: Ah, thank you @xaxxon. I'll try and update the question. I'm still curious if its possible to prevent this and why this would ever be desired.. interesting MSVC gives a warning.

Comment: If the function you wrap in a `std::function` can be called with the arguments of the `std::function`, then it's OK. The fear, uncertainty and doubt about it, is unfounded. If you don't want it, just don't ask for it.

Comment: To modify the code to accept only the precise signature that you want, is non-trivial. As I recall there are some 40+ cases to check, in general. But you can always just use an ordinary function pointer, i.e. choose to not support capturing lambdas and other stateful functors. I can't see any point in doing that, though. I can't see any advantage.

Comment: You could write your own "make_function" function that only takes functions with exactly the parameters you specify, but that would be kind of ugly.   make_function<void, int, float>(some_lambda);

Comment: When you think about std::function, remember, it holds anything that can be called with the specified types.   Just like if you write void myfunc(float a); you can't stop it from being called like: myfunc(2), a std::function behaves the same way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use for the parameter a template class which allows conversion only to `T`:

```
template <typename T>
struct Strict {
    // This is a bit simplistic, but enough for fundamental types
    Strict(T t_) : t(t_) {}

    operator T() const { return t; }

    template<typename U>
    operator U() const = delete;

    T t;
};

template <typename T>
class Thing {
public:
    using Handler = std::function<void(Strict<T>)>;
    //...
};
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58b66fddef70b62a)

Note, however, that with this approach the widening conversions won't work as well:

```
// doesn't compile
Thing<int> foo{[](long long bar){});
```

Comment: Great solution! Thanks. Works with std::bind as well: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b3ef29e8a4739d7

Comment: @moof2k No problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

For non capturing lambdas, you can rely on the fact that they decay to pointers to functions.
Use this line:

```
using Handler = void(*)(T);
```

Instead of the current definition of `Handler`.
This way you'll receive an error, unless you change the argument type to the expected type.

In other words, this (does not) work as expected:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

  template <typename T>
  class Thing {
  public:
    using Handler = void(*)(T);

    Thing(Handler handler)
    : handler_(handler)
    {}

    Handler handler_;
};

int main() {
    // switch the type of bar to double and it will compile
    Thing<double> foo([](int bar) {
        std::cout << bar;
    });

    foo.handler_(4.2);
    return 0;
}
```

Be aware that this solution no longer works if you have a capture list for your lambdas.
Anyway, it solves the issue as explained in the question.