# c++ class template prevent implicit conversion in member function

Tags: c++, templates

I wonder if it is possible to have template class where the member functions can only be called with the exact matching template type? Example:

```
template<typename T>
   struct testClass {
   void testMethod(T testParam) {};
};


int main() {
    testClass<int> testObject;
    int testInt;
    testObject(testInt);         //ok
    testObject.testMethod(1.1f); //compile error, parameter is not int
}
```

Basically an adaption for templates from this: [How do I avoid implicit conversions on non-constructing functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877546/how-do-i-avoid-implicit-conversions-on-non-constructing-functions), which I am not sure how to achieve.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use at least C++11, you can `delete` a template method with the same name

```
template <typename U>
void testMethod (U const &) = delete;
```

This way, when you call `testMethod()` with exactly a `T` value, the not-template method is preferred; when you call `testMethod()` with a value of different type, the compiler select the template `testMethod()` but is deleted so give a compilation error.

Comment: easy and works. But how does the compiler choose which function to use when both signatures are the same? Where can I find this in the c++ standard?

Comment: when the compiler must choose between a template function and a not-template function, the signatures are different; and the rule is that is preferred the not-template one when is an exact match, the template one otherwise.