# How to avoid implicitly convertible types

Tags: c++, c++17

### Update

If anybody is interested in the proceedings,[GitHub project is here](https://github.com/dbj-systems/dbj-laboratorium/tree/master/anything_but).
Although it works pretty well, I have toned it down to Arithmetic types only.

Future developments will bring more.

Thank you all

### Original Post

Yes, I know about [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877546/how-do-i-avoid-implicit-conversions-on-non-constructing-functions). please do read it for a good introduction. And one clever but not universal solution.

I do care for that but I also do need to have as *non-convertible*, some fundamental types. Having this will severely limit the possibility to introduce bugs. Not just function calls without implicit conversion allowed, but also for variable creations, assignments, comparisons etc.

I am sure this has been attempted and maybe solved before. I must not have this in my program:

```
  // implicit conversions
  // no warnings 
  {
     char character = 127 ;
     bool truth = 0 ;
     size_t size_ = truth ;
     int integer = false ;
     size_ = integer;
     size_ = character ;
  }
```

In my VS 2017 (up to date) this compiles without warnings in the default settings  even on `Level 4` aka `/W4`. Same is with clang 7, etc.

Thus far I have managed to develop this:

```
namespace dbj {
namespace util {
    using namespace std;

    template<typename T>
    struct nothing_but final
    {
        static_assert(false == std::is_array_v<T>, 
                  "can not deal with arrays");

        using type = nothing_but;

         // default creation
         nothing_but() : val_(T{}) {}
        // allowed conversion
        nothing_but(T const & t_) : val_(t_) {}
        // allowed assignment
        type & operator = (T const & new_val_)
        {
            val_ = new_val_;
            return *this;
        }

        /*
        explictly ban all attempts to construct from
        any other type but T
        */
        template<
            typename X,
            std::enable_if_t<
            false == std::is_same_v<T, X>
            , int> = 0
        >
            nothing_but(X const & x_) = delete;
        /*
        explictly ban all attempts to assign from
        any other type but T
        */
        template<
            typename X,
            std::enable_if_t<
            false == std::is_same_v<T, X>
            , int> = 0
        >
            type & operator = (X const & new_val_) = delete;

        /* conversion to X is banned */
        template<
        typename X,
        std::enable_if_t<
        false == std::is_same_v<T, X>
        , int> = 0
        >
        operator X & () = delete;

        // conversion to T is allowed, but const stays const
        operator T & () { return val_; }

        // non const value, as other std class types do
        T & data() const { return (T&)val_;  }

    private:
        T val_{};
        // compatibility
        friend bool operator < ( type const & left_, type const & right_)
        {
            return left_.val_ < right_.val_;
        }
    };
  } // util
} // dbj
```

Some quick testing:

```
{
using dbj::util::nothing_but;

nothing_but<int> si1 = 42;
si1 = 42;
nothing_but<int> si2 = 13;
//nothing_but<int> si3 = true ; 
//si3 = true;
//nothing_but<int> si4 = '$' ;
//si4 = '$';
//nothing_but<int> si5 = 2.7 ;
//si5 = 2.7;
//nothing_but<int> si6 = size_t(BUFSIZ) ;
//si6 = size_t(BUFSIZ);

si1 = si2; (void)(si1 == si2);

int j = 9;
nothing_but<int *> sip1 = &j;
nothing_but<char const *> scc1 = "OK";

char name[] = "c++";
// scc1 = name;

}
```

And some constness testing

```
{ // constnes
    const int cc = 42;
    const int cb = cc;
    nothing_but<int> const & sci1 = cc;
    nothing_but<int> const sci2 = sci1 ; // ok
    const nothing_but<int> sci3 = sci1 ; // ok

    wprintf(L"%d", sci1.data()); // ok

    //sci2 = sci1;
    //const int ii1 = sci1;
    //const int ii2 = static_cast<int>(sci1);
    //const int * ii3 = const_cast<int *>(&(sci1));
    const int & ii3 = (const int &)(sci1); // ok
    int & ii4 = (int &)(sci1); // ok
}

{ // compatibility
    // std::vector<nothing_but<bool>> bv{ true, 1 , true };
    std::vector<nothing_but<bool>> bv{ true, true , true };

    nothing_but<bool> bb = bv[1] ;
    bool kb = bb; // OK
    //int k = bb;
    //int j = bv[1];

    std::map< nothing_but<bool>, nothing_but<int> > bm;

    bm[true]  = 1;
    // bm[true]  = 2.3;
    bm[false] = 0;
    // bm[false] = 0.9;
}
```

And so on. Whatever is commented out does not compile.

So far I can see the potential but I am not sure if I am doing it right? Would you ever think of this as useful, and if you do would you do it differently?

Please do note, I need generic solution I am calling "non convertible basic types". I am hoping it can be done and it might be pretty small and generic, when done.

---

Comment: why `false == ` instead of `!`? why `mutable`?

Comment: You can use clang tool and match any implicit conversion. But I'm afraid that you got lot of warnings...

Comment: SFINAE is not even needed, as regular method taking `const T&` would be a better match anyway.

Comment: Missing default/copy constructor/assignment too.

Comment: Why must you not have `int j = 42;`?

Comment: Why are you doing the `mutable` thing, which allows `void change(int&); const nothing_but<int> THREE = 3; change(THREE);`?

Comment: @aschepler Fixed

Comment: Perhaps this is a question for [CodeReview.SE]?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think it is. Never ventured in those parts of the woods. I will now.

Comment: If you venture over that way you may want to ask the question in a way that it will be well-received there. Please review [How-to-Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) first.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using "method template overloading" rather than type_traits:

```
template<typename T>
struct nothing_but final
{
    // construction
    nothing_but() = default;
    nothing_but(const T& t_)
        : val_(t_)
    {}
    template<typename Other>
    nothing_but(const Other&) = delete;

    // assignment
    nothing_but& operator=(const T& new_val_)
    {
        val_ = new_val_;
        return *this;
    }
    template<typename Other>
    nothing_but& operator=(const Other&) = delete;

    // comparison
    bool operator==(const nothing_but& rhs) const
    {
        return (val_ == rhs.val_);
    }
    bool operator<(const nothing_but& rhs) const
    {
        return (val_ < rhs.val_);
    }

    // conversion
    operator T& ()
    {
        return val_;
    }
    template<typename Other>
    operator T& () = delete;

    // non const value, as other std class types do
    T& data() const
    {
        return (T&)val_; 
    }
    template<typename Other>
    operator Other& () = delete;

private:
    T val_{};
};
```

Non-templates are preferred over templates (see C++ standard 13.3.3, or explained in http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/049.htm).

Comment: @ Lorenz Zhao, this is indeed very simple and very functional solution Great. +1 for simplification. Simpler code is always better.