# C++ - How to handle/avoid char to int implicit conversion into a function argument

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

I don't want  my code to compile or handle invalid input / argument. In this case, it should only accept int variables and nothing else.

```
#include <iostream>
class calc{
public:
    int add2(int x){
       return x + 2;
    }
};

// Inside testing file    
int main(){
calc c;
// Should not output anything / throw error since argument is 'a' and not a integer 
 std::cout<<c.add2('a'); // But it outputs 99. 
}
```

I understand c++ is doing its implicit conversion here but I don't know how to stop it from happening. Or is there a way to check if the input passed is of int type and nothing else?

Comment: You could add `int add2(char) = delete;` , I suppose.

Comment: I want to handle bool , float, and any other data types that would convert to int implicitly. So I was wondering if there is a universal way to do it and not just for chat. Basically I want to handle all invalid input

Comment: I have no idea what that means, but if you want to explicitly *error* on explicitly *char* what I showed would do it. If you want to compile-time-error on everything but truly `int` you could always use sfinae and `template<class T> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T,int>::value, int> add2(T x)`

Comment: @PrateekArora I don't fully understand. What is "invalid input"? Do you want to allow implicit conversion for some types, or prohibit it for all types except `int`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I avoid implicit conversions on non-constructing functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12877546/how-do-i-avoid-implicit-conversions-on-non-constructing-functions)

Comment: @PrateekArora, the point is that `char` _is_ convertible to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

The point is that `char` *is* convertible to `int`, so what you wrote in a comment

> I want to handle bool , float, and any other data types that would convert to int implicitly

is already true for your code. So you probably want to just prevent the conversion to `char`. If that's the case, you can template the function and `static_assert` inside it that `T` be convertible to `int` but it's not `char`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
class calc {
public:
    template<typename T>
    T add2(T x) {
        static_assert(std::is_convertible_v<T, int> && !std::is_same_v<T, char>);
        return x + 2;
    }
};

int main() {
    calc c;

    //std::cout << c.add2('a'); // fails
    std::cout << c.add2(1); // works
    std::cout << c.add2(1.5); // works
    std::cout << c.add2(1.5f); // works
    std::cout << c.add2(15ll); // works
}
```