# Is it possible to prevent implicit bool <-> int conversions?

Tags: c++, boolean

Given this code:

```
void foo(int bar, bool stuff)
{
}

enum class Mode
{ 
  SomeMode_1,  SomeMode_2,
};

void foo2(int bar, Mode stuff)
{
}

int main()
{
  foo(1, true);              // (1) compiles as expected
  foo(true, 2);              // (2) compiles as expected, but unwanted
  foo2(1, Mode::SomeMode_1); // (3) compiles as expected

  foo2(1, 1);                // (4) does not compile as expected
  foo(1, Mode::SomeMode_1);  // (5) does not compile as expected
  foo(Mode::SomeMode_1, 1);  // (6) does not compile as expected
}
```

In case (2) the arguments have inadvertently been swapped, but it compiles because of `bool` and `int` being converted implicitly to each other.

Should I change the signature of `void foo(int bar, bool stuff)` and rather use a `class enum` instead of a `bool` for type safety? Or is there any other method to prevent the implicit conversion of `bool` to integral types and vice versa?

Comment: The duplicate provides the generic way but here you can simply delete the non-allowed version, `void foo(bool, int) = delete;`.

Comment: @Holt Like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12877563/ I guess?

Comment: @Holt that's exactly what I need. I wasn't aware that `= delete` could be used for non member functions too.

Comment: Or `template<typename type_t> auto f(type_t x) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<bool,type_t>,void> {}`

Comment: Or `template <typename A, typename B> void foo(A, B) = delete;` to disallow anything other than the desired exact types — no implicit conversions.